# Is it really necessary to have GROUP BY in the SQL standard

Tags: ansi-sql, sql

After writing SQL for a few years, I find it often annoying having to put the columns I am interested in `SELECT` and then specify them again in `GROUP BY`. I can't help thinking, why do we have to do that?

What is the reason that user has to be specific about which column to group by? Can't we just let the SQL engine assume **if there is an aggregate function in `SELECT`, group by the rest non-aggregate columns**?

This will be especially helpful and more concise when you have a large `CASE WHEN` in `SELECT`.

Comment: You still need GROUP BY when you want to group more attribute than those expressed in SELECT. For instance, if you want to group R(A,B,C) on A and B and then select only B and SUM(C), or something similar.

Comment: After spending a few decades writing the compilers for various flavors of SQL, I'm fairly certain those compiler writers discovered some valid fundamental reasons to do the same thing pretty much the same way in each of their programs. I can't say if they were right or wrong, but I'd imagine there are very few people who can question their reasoning. Plus, in my experience, allowing assumptions (especially in code) can be a bit problematic at times.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because they may not always match exactly.

For example, If I want find out the maximum number of books per category, I could do:

```
select max(cnt)
from (
    select count(*) as cnt
    from books
    group by category
    ) t;
```

In some DBs such as Oracle, you can even do this:

```
select max(count(*))
from books
group by category;
```

I don't really need to specify the category column as I don't need it.

A few databases such as Postgres support the use of aliases in the group by clause.

Answer (score 2):

I happen to sort of agree with you.  If someone wanted a more esoteric `group by` -- say, leaving out columns -- then they could use a subquery.

If I had to guess, the writers of SQL did not want to imbue so much power in aggregation functions.  Your suggestion would mean that a function in the `select` is determining the definition of the row in the result set.  Normally, `select` just determines the columns.  That is, it is one thing for a query to fail *syntactically* because an aggregation is included without a `group by`.  It is another thing for a function in the `select` to change the rows being output.

You can use window functions with `select distinct`.  Although I don't recommend the syntax, you can do:

```
select distinct x, count(*) over (partition by x)
from t;
```

Well, this eliminates the `group by`, but you still have to repeat the grouping criteria in each window function.

Answer (score 1):

You have to imagine that you’re working with two versions of the table here. For example:

```
SELECT …
FROM table
GROUP BY …;
```

First, remember that the `SELECT` is evaluated *after* the `FROM` anbd `GROUP BY` clauses. That means that what you can select is limited by the results of those clauses.

The thing is to imagine that the `GROUP BY` generates a new *virtual* table. This virtual table only has the following:

- The grouped columns
- *Summaries* (aggregates) of all columns
- Nothing else

There will be one row of summaries for each *distinct* group.

If you want a particular column in your `SELECT` clause, it must be either a group column or a summary, since you can only `SELECT` from what’s available.

Even without a `GROUP BY` clause, there is an implicit `GROUP BY ()` which results in a single row of summaries. Some DBMSs (not all) even allow you to add that, though it doesn’t change anything.

Note that the number of rows in the `GROUP BY` summary is affected by the number of columns you are grouping. In general, the number of rows will be something like (DISTINCT Group1)*(DISTINCT GROUP2) etc. That means you certainly don’t want to group by more than you really need.

**Exceptions**

Suppose you have a statement like this:

```
SELECT state, name, count(*)
FROM customers
GROUP BY state;
```

This, of course, would fail. What meaning would there be select the `name` where there are multiple values for one state?

However, MySQL, in traditional mode, will let you do just that: it will select *one* name to go with the state. However, there is no guarantee which one, so it’s of dubious value.

Suppose you you want to group by month. You may wish to display the month name, but sort by the month number. Here you will need to group by both. Using pseudo date functions:

```sql
SELECT monthname, count(*)
FROM data
GROUP BY monthname, monthnumber
ORDER BY monthnumber;
```

This is nothing more than a workaround. It takes advantage of the fact that for each month name there is exactly one month number, to there is no real further grouping. It’s just there to get both values in the `GROUP BY` virtual table.